# usb_modeswitch with USB dongle 3G on qemu

Tags: 3g, qemu, openwrt, dongle

I am trying to use a dongle 3G within qemu with openwrt environment. Dongle ref : HUAWEi - K4605.

First I have patch kernel sources in option.c :

```
--- option.c    2010-12-09 22:29:45.000000000 +0100
+++ option.c    2012-11-12 17:39:17.000000000 +0100
@@ -165,6 +165,7 @@
 #define HUAWEI_PRODUCT_E143D           0x143D
 #define HUAWEI_PRODUCT_E143E           0x143E
 #define HUAWEI_PRODUCT_E143F           0x143F
+#define HUAWEI_PRODUCT_E14C6           0x14C6
 #define HUAWEI_PRODUCT_K4505           0x1464
 #define HUAWEI_PRODUCT_K3765           0x1465
 #define HUAWEI_PRODUCT_E14AC           0x14AC
@@ -477,6 +478,7 @@
    { USB_DEVICE_AND_INTERFACE_INFO(HUAWEI_VENDOR_ID, HUAWEI_PRODUCT_E143E, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff) },
    { USB_DEVICE_AND_INTERFACE_INFO(HUAWEI_VENDOR_ID, HUAWEI_PRODUCT_E143F, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff) },
    { USB_DEVICE_AND_INTERFACE_INFO(HUAWEI_VENDOR_ID, HUAWEI_PRODUCT_K4505, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff) },
+   { USB_DEVICE_AND_INTERFACE_INFO(HUAWEI_VENDOR_ID, HUAWEI_PRODUCT_E14C6, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff) },
    { USB_DEVICE_AND_INTERFACE_INFO(HUAWEI_VENDOR_ID, HUAWEI_PRODUCT_K3765, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff) },
    { USB_DEVICE_AND_INTERFACE_INFO(HUAWEI_VENDOR_ID, HUAWEI_PRODUCT_ETS1220, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff) },
    { USB_DEVICE_AND_INTERFACE_INFO(HUAWEI_VENDOR_ID, HUAWEI_PRODUCT_E14AC, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff) },
```

I have also install kernel module as kmod-usb-serial-option or kmod-usb-uhci.
Next, I have disable auto usb_modeswitch on host machine in /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf.

My dongle have two product/vendor id, 12d1:14c1 when we are using it in storage mod, and 12d1:14c6 in dongle 3G mod. I run my qemu with usb option :

```
-usb -usbdevice host:12d1:14c6 -usbdevice host:12d1:14c1
```

I detect my device on my qemu machine with lsusb in storage mod. Now I have to switch it with : `/usr/bin/usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 14c1 -W -M "55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"`

This step is not working. After putting some debugging code in usb_modeswitch.c, I can see that usb_bulk_write is working but the usb_bulk_read never respond. I modified sources of usb_modeswitch to remove limitless waiting of usb_bulk_read. Thanks to this modification, I can see with lsusb that my dongle success to switch but dev entry ttyUSB0 is not create in /dev...

trace of usb_modeswitch is :

> ```
> root@OpenWrt:~# /usr/bin/usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 14c1 -W -M "55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
> scsi 2:0:0:0: CD-ROM            Vodafone CD ROM (Huawei)  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
> scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Vodafone Storage (Huawei)      PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
> sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
>
> Taking all parameters from the command line
>
>
>  usb_modeswitch: handle USB devices with multiple modes
>  Version 1.2.3 (C) Josua Dietze 2012
>  Based on libusb0 (0.1.12 and above)
>
>  PLEASE REPORT NEW CONFIGURATIONS !
>
> DefaultVendor=  0x12d1
> DefaultProduct= 0x14c1
> TargetVendor=   not set
> TargetProduct=  not set
> TargetClass=    not set
> TargetProductList=""
>
> DetachStorageOnly=0
> HuaweiMode=0
> SierraMode=0
> SonyMode=0
> QisdaMode=0
> GCTMode=0
> KobilMode=0
> SequansMode=0
> MobileActionMode=0
> CiscoMode=0
> MessageEndpoint=  not set
> MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
> NeedResponse=0
> ResponseEndpoint= not set
>
> InquireDevice enabled (default)
> Success check disabled
> System integration mode disabled
>
>
> Looking for default devices ...
>   searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0001
>   searching devices, found USB ID 0409:55aa
>   searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:14c1
>    found matching vendor ID
>    found matching product ID
>    adding device
>  Found device in default mode, class or configuration (1)
> Accessing device 003 on bus 001 ...
> Getting the current device configuration ...
>  OK, got current device configuration (1)
> Using first interface: 0x00
> Using endpoints 0x01 (out) and 0x81 (in)
> Inquiring device details; driver will be detached ...
> Looking for active driver ...
>  OK, driver found; name unknown, limitation of libusb1
>  OK, driver "unkown" detached
>  Could not get INQUIRY response (error -110)
>
> USB description data (for identification)
> -------------------------
> Manufacturer: Vodafone Group (Huawei) 
>      Product: Vodafone Mobile Broadband (Huawei) 
>   Serial No.: not provided
> -------------------------
> Looking for active driver ...
>  No driver found. Either detached before or never attached
> Setting up communication with interface 0
> Using endpoint 0x01 for message sending ...
> Trying to send message 1 to endpoint 0x01 ...
>  OK, message successfully sent
> Resetting response endpoint 0x81
> libusb:error [op_clear_halt] clear_halt failed error -1 errno 32
>  Could not reset endpoint (probably harmless): -34
> Resetting message endpoint 0x01
> libusb:error [op_clear_halt] clear_halt failed error -1 errno 32
>  Could not reset endpoint (probably harmless): -34
> usb 1-2.1: USB disconnect, address 3
>  Device is gone, skipping any further commands
> -> Run lsusb to note any changes. Bye.
> ```

Someone have a solution ? Do I have to configure qemu in a certain way to send msg to my dongle through bulk endpoint ?

Thanks,